# How to write the path without hardcoding the value in grep command

Tags: python, string

I want to use variable instead of using the hard coded path. I have written this 2 line:

```
>>> os.system('grep "VST_Marked:" "/home/ppothal/trial/build/input/spm_parameters.yaml" | grep false')

VST_Marked: false

0
```

It is returning exact line that works fine for me. if I have assigned this path to one varibale, it is showing no such directory present/. please see below lines.

```
>>> IN_PATH ="/home/ppothal/trial/build/input/spm_parameters.yaml"

>>> os.system('grep "VST_Marked:" IN_PATH | grep false')
grep: IN_PATH: No such file or directory

256
```

can anyone help me regarding this.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`printf`-style formating](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting):

```
IN_PATH ="/home/ppothal/trial/build/input/spm_parameters.yaml"
os.system('grep "VST_Marked:" %s | grep false' % IN_PATH)
```

or [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
IN_PATH ="/home/ppothal/trial/build/input/spm_parameters.yaml"
os.system('grep "VST_Marked:" {} | grep false'.format(IN_PATH))
```